# Similar Express routing requests with different outputs

Tags: express, routes, api-design

I have written two different Express routing requests that refer to a single Object (which has movies and data relative to each movie). They are supposed to display different results, but are structurally exactly the same. However, one works and the other one does not. Here is the code:

**Movies by title**

```
app.get("/movies/:title", (req, res) => {
  res.json(Movies.find((movie) => {
    return movie.title === req.params.title
  }));
});
```

**Movies by genre** - this one is not working

```
app.get("/movies/:genre", (req, res) => {
  res.json(Movies.find((movie) => {
    return movie.genre === req.params.genre
  }));
});
```

They refer to the following object:

```
let Movies = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "Night of the Living Dead",
    genre: "Classical",
    director: {
      name: "George P. Romero",
      bio: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
      birth: "01/01/1900",
      death: "01/01/1900"
    },
    imgUrl: "https://z.com/1/img/thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "28 days later",
    genre: "Apocalypse",
    director: {
      name: "Danny Boyle",
      bio: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur",
      birth: "01/01/1900",
      death: "01/01/1900"
    },
    imgUrl: "https://z.com/2/img/thumb.jpg"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Cell",
    genre: "Apocalypse",
    director: {
      name: "Christopher Hatton",
      bio: "ipsum dolor sit",
      birth: "01/01/1900",
      death: "01/01/1900"
    },
    imgUrl: "https://z.com/3/img/thumb.jpg"
  }
];
```

The first one works fine with the request localhost:8080/movies/Lorem Ipsum, but the second fail to the request localhost:8080/movies/Classical or any other.

The functional calls of Express and the app on the top of the file are ok (it works for the first routing request.

I'd appreciate any enlightenment. Thanks in advance for the availability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you're using the same pattern for the two routes. You try to match two routes with the pattern : `/movies/:parameter`. For every requests, Express try to match the request path with registered urls in the application. With the given example :

```
/movies/Lorem Ipsum # Match the /movies/:title
/movies/Classical # Match the /movies/:title
```

Why ? Because the route `/movies/:title` is the first in the declaration order. The name of the parameter doesn't count, because when you're sending your request, express doesn't know that "Lorem ipsum" is a `title` and "Classical" is a `genre` ! The name of the parameter in the route declaration is only there to call it in your handler with `req.params.title` by example.

## How to fix that ?

Change your pattern, use the query instead (https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#req.query) ! You can use this form :

```
GET /movies?genre=Classical
GET /movies?title=Lorem%20Ipsum
```

And you will have a route like this :

```
app.get('/movies', (req, res) => {
    if (req.query.title)
         // do title research
    else if (req.query.genre)
         // do genre research

    ...
});
```

Have fun !

Comment: your answer was so good that Stack Overflow will need to create a higher level of worshipping for its quality. You answered questions I still hadn't realised I would have. A last newbie thing: how should I write the conditions for those if-else lines you suggested? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Oh thanks a lot ! It cheers me up :) you can try something like this, it exist maybe something cleverer but i think this way is pretty simple and comprehensible :

app.get("/movies", (req, res) => {
  const { genre, title } = req.query

  if (!genre || !title)
    res.status(422).json({ error: 'genre or title must be set'})

  if (genre && genre != '')
    return res.json(Movies.find((movie) => movie.genre === genre))
  else if (title && title != '')
    return res.json(Movies.find((movie) => movie.title === title))
  else
    return res.json(Movies.findAll())
})